# Installing Remote Tools for Visual Studio

Tags: windows, tablet

When trying to install the Remote Tools for Visual Studio on my Windows Tablet , I am facing issues as the setup gets stuck on 'Initializing' and does not move ahead. I am trying to install on a Windows Tablet which is running 32 bit Operating System and 2 GB ram.

Comment: I experienced the same problem running the `x64` version of the `.exe`. Make sure you are using the right version for your system (x86 vs x64), and the right version for your VS.